# TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.people.map')

Tags: reactjs

1. I am getting 'undefined' is not an object error when running test cases. Here is the actual code.

   ```
   class People extends React.Component{
       displayAlert (email){
          alert(email);
    }

   render (){
    return (
       <div>{
           <ul key = {this.props.id}>
               <li>
                   <button onClick= {this.displayAlert.bind(this, this.props.email)}>{this.props.lastName + ', ' + this.props.firstName}</button>
               </li>
           </ul>}
       </div>
     );
    }
   }

   class PersonList extends React.Component{
   render () {
    /* people is an array of people*/
     var items = this.props.people.map( function ( item ){
       return <People id = {item.id} email = {item.email} firstName = {item.firstName} lastName = {item.lastName}> </People>
   });

   return (
       <div> {items} </div>
     )
    }
   }
   React.render( <PersonList people={ people } />, el );
   ```
2. Also, I have a test case to check "person-list has an instance for every person". But it fails too. Here is the test case and the error message

   ```
   it( `has an instance for every person`, () => {
      let persons = scryRenderedComponentsWithType( list, PersonItem );
      expect( persons.length ).to.equal( people.length );
   } );
   ```

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) person-list has an instance for every person FAILED
        AssertionError: expected 1 to equal 2

3. I have another test case to make sure There is no extra elements. But It fails too. Here is the test case and the error

   ```
   it( `doesn't have extra elements`, () => {
       expect( domnode.querySelectorAll( '> :not( ul )' ).length ).to.equal( 0 );
      expect( domnode.querySelectorAll( '> ul > :not( li )' ).length ).to.equal( 0 );

   } );
   ```

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) person-list doesn't have extra elements FAILED
        the domexception "Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12" was thrown, throw an Error :)

Comment: It should also tell you exactly where the error occurred.

Comment: Could you show us how you set up your test data and your tests?